# How did older games manage their sprites?

Tags: textures, memory

I’m aware that older games would reuse sprites as much as possible (Like the bushes and clouds in Mario, or slime and red slime in dragon quest), how did they manage their sprites? Did they preload everything at the beginning, or did they load and unload as needed?

I had assumed the latter, but many games on the seas genesis, snes, gbc, etc have a sprite test mode which leads me to believe that they simply preloaded everything. Or is it possible that they used a combination of the two?

Comment: Obviously some preloaded, some loaded and unload. What is the real question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how other games accomplished a particular technique.

Comment: There are many old games & they don't necessarily handle sprites the same way. Even if you picked one game, unless someone from the dev team is here, it's unlikely that we'll know exactly what they did. If you feel that knowing the answer might help you with a problem you're having about your own game, please ask about that problem instead.

Comment: @JoshPetrie My apologies, I didn't know this would be considered off-topic here. The question was originally posted on Arqade, but I directed the OP here

Comment: @Wondercricket No worries :)

Comment: Answer: If you look into EMULATORS of NES, SNES, and SEGA Genesis, you can quickly guess they used a kind of tiling system with a palette. Most of those emulators (Genecyst, if I recall correctly, is an example) have a feature to actually edit the palette in runtime - while the game is playing.

Comment: Answer x2: I don't know how and when is the palette loaded, but it is part of the resource (part of the ROM). Even architectures like GameBoy Advance have a kind of dedicated memory space to store that sort of resources (so your hypothesis of resources preload is accurate at least to some extent), needed in almost real time.

Comment: Even if I cannot cover extensively all the technologies you ask for, at least it is the case for Genesis, NES, and GBA.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing sprites is a different thing than loading everything from the beginning.
Both techniques are used either together or separate.

The example you mentioned with clouds and bushes simply means that the game loads one sprite (the cloudy-bush thingy) and uses it to draw both the bushes and the clouds. So only one sprite exists in memory, but multiple things are drawn on the screen (with some colour alternation).

Preloading everything from the beginning is another issue. In some cases you don't have the luxury of a good CPU to load a lot of data on the fly, so perhaps it is better to load everything on the beginning, especially if the game is small. It is also cheaper to include multiple sprites into a single texture, so if a game (like the old ones) is small enough to fit all sprites in a texture, then they load everything anyway.

What should you use? In today's hardware, nobody really comes to that issue. If you use a library to handle graphics for you, then you only declare when you will use them, and it's the library's responsibility to decide when to load them.

Unless you are advanced enough to want to make games for older consoles with harder programming languages like assembly, such a person would know how to load graphics manually depending on the platform.

For more information it would be better to ask the teams that actually made older games.